# Rails linking multiples row's id in a table to a single row in another table SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a calendar app in which the user can create multiple calendar and add multiple entries to each different calendar in Rails. For instance, I have the following table

Entry

```
id          description
----------------------------------------------------
1           go shopping
2           go to cinema
3           do homework
```

Calendar

```
id    entry_id      
----------------
1     1, 3
2     2
3     1, 2, 3
```

What would be the association/solution if I want to get all the entries from a row (in array?) in the calendar and how do would I add a new entry to the row? (I looked at the has_and_belongs_to_many association but it seems to require a third table which isn't as direct as having multiple ids assigned to a single row...)

Comment: What do you mean by **which isn't as direct as having multiple ids assigned to a single row**?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't know how to explain but I have seen some tables in some forum's database where a forum row could contain multiples subforum's id separated by a comma. Maybe it was pretty outdated and the best way now is to have a third table containing the linkage between the two row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to have to do crazy joins later you would probably want to have a join table.  Yes the third table is a good idea here.

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :calendars, through: :scheduling
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :entries, through: scheduling
end

class Scheduling < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entry
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

Then tables look like this:

```
entires
  id:integer
  description:string

calendars
  id:integer

schedulings
  id:integer
  calendar_id:integer
  entry_id:integer
```

And your ActiveRecord queries look like this:

```
Calendar.find(3).entries.ids  #=> [1, 2, 3]
Entry.find(1).calendars.ids   #=> [1, 3]
```

The rails guide also provide a great example:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Comment: I see.. Thanks for your answer!